# How to set class-level permissions through CLI or Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform

The official blog mentioned setting class-level permissions through the data browser.

http://blog.parse.com/2014/07/07/parse-security-ii-class-hysteria/

Is there any way to do the same through CLI or Cloud Code?

It's needed for the automation of the installation process of our app on Parse.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately those features are only available from the Data Browser.

Sounds like it could be an interesting feature request. I'm not sure if there's an official channel for making feature requests (maybe a bug report?) but you could try the Google Group page, you can find the link here:

https://parse.com/help/

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your answer. I'll try to send a request there.

Comment: Did you get any where with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke REST API like they mention here.

http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#pointer-permissions

(this was also obtained by looking at the inspector Parse Dashboard)

```
//POST http://localhost:8000/parse/schemas/Post
{
  "classLevelPermissions": {
    "get": {
      "*": true,
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "find": {
      "*": true,
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "create": {
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "update": {
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "delete": {
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "addField": {
      "*": true,
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "readUserFields": [
      "owner"
    ],
    "writeUserFields": [
      "owner"
    ]
  },
  "_method": "PUT",
  "_ApplicationId": "MY_APPLICATION_ID",
  "_ClientVersion": "js1.6.14",
  "_MasterKey": "MY_MASTER_KEY",
  "_InstallationId": "e703b6b0-c992-92af-3cf7-3b1ad09739cd"
}
```